# find last location in a string

Tags: c++, string

i have a string

a = "hai my name is prasanth Madhavan"

and i would like to replace the space btw prasanth and Madhavan with a period.

when i use a.find("prasanth") it gives the location of p i.e the begining of the search string. is ther a way to get the location of the ending of the string using find??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <string>

std::string str("hai my name is prasanth Madhavan");
std::string prasanth("prasanth");
std::size_t prasanth_pos = str.find(prasanth);
if (prasanth_pos != std::string::npos && prasanth_pos + prasanth.size() != str.size())
    str[prasanth_pos + prasanth.size()] = '.';
```

Comment: You should also check whether `prasanth_pos + prasanth.size()` is still a valid index. The string could very well end in just "prasanth".

Comment: Much simpler is to just find `"prasanth "`, with the space, since that is, in correctness, what you're trying to find. Then you know there's a space there to replace.

Comment: @GMan: yeah, it was my first thought, but then I rejected it as more "tricky" and not so readable

Answer (score 2):

Add the length of the string you are looking for.